# ¿Como hacer que solo se puedan seleccionar documentos pdf con cierto tamaño en fileInput?

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

Tengo un formulario donde guardo varios documentos, pero me gustaría poder limitarlos a un tamaño máximo y que sean pdf, pero no logro hacer que al seleccionar el documento solo aparezca documentos con el tamaño y tipo de documento adecuado.

Como está ahorita me muestra los alert de error si son más pesados o no son pdf al igual si son documentos válidos, pero a la hora de seleccionar, me muestra todos los documentos del directorio donde se está consultando.

Este es mi código del Template

```
<script>
$('.clearablefileinput').change( function() {
    if(this.files[0].size > 5120000)
    { // 5120000 bytes = 5000 Kb
        alert("El documento tiene un tamaño mayor a 5 Mb");
        $(this).val('');
    }

    else
    {
        var formato = (this.files[0].name).split('.').pop();

        if(formato.toLowerCase() == 'pdf')
        {
            alert("Documento Válido");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Solo se admiten documentos PDF");
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Ya leíste [ésto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)?

Comment: ya, pensé que se podía hacer con jquery o por código en python, ya que eran varios campos quería evitar hacer el formulario manualmente

Comment: Igual puedes hacerlo desde python. Depende como estés manejando tu formulario